# Group and Sum a List<object[]>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this `List<object[]>`

```
List<object[]> olst = new List<object[]>();

olst.Add(new object[] { "AA1", 1 });
olst.Add(new object[] { "AA2", 1 });
olst.Add(new object[] { "AA2", 1 });
olst.Add(new object[] { "AA1", 1 });
olst.Add(new object[] { "AA1", 1 });
```

From `olst`, I need to produce a new `List<object>` to hold this:

```
"AA1", 3
"AA2", 2
```

In other words, I need to group **olst[x][0]** and sum up **olst[x][1]**.
I could use a for loop, but I was hoping someone could help me using lambda expressions and/or linq to accomplish this.

Comment: You might want to consider using `Tuple<string,int>` instead of an object array.  Or write your own class to handles these values.  That way you'll have strong typing and won't need to do casts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) and [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx):

```
List<object[]> newList = olst
    /* Group the list by the element at position 0 in each item */
    .GroupBy(o => o[0].ToString())
    /* Project the created grouping into a new object[]: */
    .Select(i => new object[]
    {
        i.Key,
        i.Sum(x => (int)x[1])
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will turn you list into a dictionary mapping from the first value to the sum of the second values with the same first value.

```
var result = olst.GroupBy(entry => (String)entry[0])
                 .Select(group => new Object[]
                                  {
                                      group.Key,
                                      group.Sum(item => (Int32)item[1])
                                   })
                 .ToList();
```

I missed the part stating the the result should be of type `List<Object>` containing `Object[]`. It would help if the downvoters would leave a comment about the why. ;)