# Group a List<object[]>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a question that's similar to [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962393/group-and-sum-a-listobject).
I've got this List<object[]>

```
List<object[]> olst = new List<object[]>();

olst.Add(new object[] { "AA1", "X", 1, 3.50 });
olst.Add(new object[] { "AA2", "Y", 2, 5.20 });
olst.Add(new object[] { "AA2", "Y", 1, 3.50 });
olst.Add(new object[] { "AA1", "X", 1, 3.20 });
olst.Add(new object[] { "AA1", "Y", 2, 5.30 });
```

I need to produce List<object[]> to hold this:

```
"AA1", "X", 2, 6.70
"AA2", "Y", 3, 8.70
"AA1", "Y", 2, 5.30
```

In other words, I need to group olst by the **1st** and **2nd** elements of each object[] and sum **3rd** and **4th**.
I could use a for loop, but I was hoping someone could help me using lambda expressions and/or linq to accomplish this.

Comment: Why are you using an `object[]` to hold onto strings.  If you know they're strings, use a `string[]`.  Or, better yet, create a new type with two meaningful properties to represent these two values.

Comment: @Servy - this is just an example.

Comment: If you know that you are working with a pair, rather than with some unknown number, then a Tuple<,> or KeyValuePair<,> might be idiomatic.

Comment: @Administrateur So what does that mean?  Does it mean they won't always be strings?  If so, that's rather important.  Are the size of the arrays known to always be two?  Do we know what all of the possible types it could be are?  Or are you just saying you didn't bother to type the array properly?

Comment: @Servy He is probably saying that he is more concerned with how to group the elements in the array then what those elements are.  If knowing the type of the element is important then I would suggest adding an answer which covers the most common types and add a blurb indicating the limitations.

Comment: @Trisped - Exactly, thank you. I just need a little help grouping the elements.

Comment: @Trisped Knowing the types are quite relevant.  If the number of items aren't exact it greatly increases the complexity of the solution.  If the types aren't all the same, or each column isn't the same, then that adds a major level of complexity.  If the types don't have a meaningful `Equal` and `GetHashCode` value then that needs to be accounted for, again adding further complexity.  However, if the data is all as simple as this case, none of that's relevant and it would be needlessly confusing the reader and would be offtopic, hence I ask what the data is really like.

Comment: @Administrateur And we need help knowing the requirements to do it.  You can't just say "it doesn't matter" because I'm telling you that it does.  The existing answers are making the assertions that I'm asking about, if those assertions don't hold true, then those answers won't work.  If they do hold true, you should adjust the question so that it's clear.

Comment: @Servy - fair enough... to give a better example, add an int and a double to the end of each array. The desired result would be to group by 1st and 2nd elements and sum 3rd and 4th.

Comment: @Administrateur That's adding a significant amount of complexity to the issue, and you'll need to actually edit the question itself if that's really what you need to do.

Comment: @Administrateur Also, if each "column" will have the same data type, but not all columns will have the same data type, it's further evidence that you should create a custom type to represent each item in the list, rather than using an `object[]`.  That will allow you to have strongly typed access to each item, know the number of items, and be able to give meaningful names to the data.

Comment: Edited the question... sorry for all the confusion. All arrays have 4 elements (string, string, int, double).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21477/discussion-between-administrateur-and-servy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group by an anonymous type, then sum the third and fourth columns:

```
List<object[]> grouped = olst
    .GroupBy(o => new { Prop1 = o[0].ToString(), Prop2 = o[1].ToString() })
    .Select(o => new object[] 
    {
        o.Key.Prop1,
        o.Key.Prop2,
        o.Sum(x => (int)x[2]),
        o.Sum(x => (double)x[3])
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
List<object[]> olst = new List<object[]>();

            olst.Add(new object[] { "AA1", "X" });
            olst.Add(new object[] { "AA2", "Y" });
            olst.Add(new object[] { "AA2", "Y" });
            olst.Add(new object[] { "AA1", "X" });
            olst.Add(new object[] { "AA1", "Y" });

            var result = from ol in olst
                         group ol by new {p1 = ol[0], p2 = ol[1]}
                         into g
                         select g.First();
```

Something like this?

Comment: you'd want to select `g.First()`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I would go with `Tuple` and maybe use HashSet instead, since it will only append if item doesn't exist (also, it is fast). If you add items to hashset, there's no need to select distinct as long as your type provides necessary Equals and GetHashCode methods.
Something like this:

```
var olst = new HashSet<Tuple<string,string>>();
            olst.Add(Tuple.Create("AA1", "X"));
            olst.Add(Tuple.Create("AA1", "X"));
            olst.Add(Tuple.Create("AA2", "Y"));
            olst.Add(Tuple.Create("AA2", "Y"));
```

If you need you can convert it to list. Here's an example:

```
olst.ToList().ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x.Item1 + " " + x.Item2));
```

Will print out

```
AA1 X
AA2 Y
```

Comment: If the types of the objects aren't all the same, and if there isn't a consistent number of elements (the OP is refusing to confirm or deny either of these assertions) then this solution won't work.

Comment: @Servy, Yeah, I'm aware of that. Just a possible solution. That's all I can infer from the OP question at this point unfortunately. Thanks for pointing it out though.